How to calculate concordance index for Cox with stratified piecewise?
from lifelines import CoxPHFitter
cph_19a = CoxPHFitter(baseline_estimation_method='piecewise', breakpoints=[2,6,11]) 
model19a = cph_19a.fit(df_m18a,'T12',event_col='E12',strata=['Sexo_M', 'PE_Agrup_ING CIVIL', 'CatPase'] )
# The censored observations are all right censored at the end of the study

The problem is that I need the concordance index but seems that is not possible to calculate it with lifelines for this case. I tried with the following code:
try:
    cph_19a.concordance_index_
except Exception as e:
    print(e) #CoxPHFitter has no attribute 'concordance_index_'

try:
    cph_19a.predict_hazard(df_m18a_test)
except Exception as e:
    print(e) #cannot reshape array of size 10224 into shape (12,1)

# Therefore, the concordance_index() function is not executed either:
try:
    concordance_index(df_m18a['T12'], -cph_19a.predict_hazard(df_m18a,times=12), df_m18a['E12'])
except Exception as e:
    print(e) 

Do I have to develop my own function for a stratified piecewise model using CoxPH?
